# SQL - Finding optional value in another table

Tags: sql

In the scenario where there are two tables, one column in the first has a nullable key to another table.

```sql
table1_id | table1_key | table2_id | table2_value
----------+------------+-----------+--------------
    1     |     1      |     1     |      3       
    2     |            |           |              
    3     |     3      |     3     |      1       
    4     |     1      |     1     |      3
```

With a single efficient statement, I want to get all rows from table1 and data from table2 if they exist.
My current method does a union between two statements.

```sql
SELECT
    table1.id    as table1_id,
    table1.fkey  as table1_key,
    table2.id    as table2_id,
    table2.value as table_value
FROM
    table1,
    table2
WHERE
    table1.fkey = table2.id
UNION
SELECT
    table1.id    as table1_id,
    null,
    null,
    null
FROM
    table1,
    table2
WHERE
    table1.fkey = NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table2)
```

How can this be done more efficiently in a single select statement?

Comment: Use LEFT OUTER JOIN. if you can provide me expected data then i will show the exact query.

Comment: You should always tag your question with the database engine you are using. Are you using MySQL? You should also use correct [join syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) when joining tables in a query.

Comment: Agree wrt tagging right database however I believe `LEFT OUTER JOIN` syntax will work atleast with MySQL,SQL server,Postgres SQL and Oracle. Normally with all standard SQL engine it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A left join would do the job,

```
SELECT
    table1.id    as table1_id,
    table1.fkey  as table1_key,
    table2.id    as table2_id,
    table2.value as table_value
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
  ON table1.fkey = table2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a join between `table1` and `table2` on the foreign key relationship.
From your question, I understand that column `fkey` in `table1` is a foreign key to column `id` in `table2`.
You want to retrieve rows from `table1` even if there is no matching row in `table2`. Hence you need a *left outer join*

```sql
select t1.id as t1_id
      ,t1.fkey as t2_id
      ,t2.value as t2_value
  from table1 t1
  left outer join table2 t2
    on t1.fkey = t2.id
```